# Listing BigQuery Tables in `huge/big` Datasets - 30K-40K+ tables

Tags: google-bigquery

The task is to **programmatically** list all the tables within the given dataset with more than 30-40K tables

Initial option we explored was using `tables.list` API (as we do all the times for normal datasets with reasonable number of tables in them)

Looks like this API returns max 1000 entries (even if we try to set `maxResults` to bigger value)
To take next 1000 we need to “wait” for response of previous request then extract `pageToken` and repeat call and so on
For the datasets with 30K – 40K+ this can take up to 10-15 and more sec (under good weather)
So the timing is a problem for us that we want to address!

In above mentioned calls we are getting back only `nextPageToken` and `tables/tableReference/tableId` so size of response is extremely small!

> Question:

Is there way to somehow increase `maxResults`, so to get all tables in one (or very few) call(s) (assuming it will be much faster than doing 30-40 calls)?

The workaround we tried so far is to use __TABLES_SUMMARY__ with `jobs.insert` or `jobs.query` API.
This way – the whole result is returned within the seconds – but in our particular case – using BigQuery `jobs` API is not an option for multiple reasons. We want to be able to use `list` API

Comment: Just out of curiosity - how does the BigQuery Web UI display such a dataset?

Comment: Yes, I get your question Mikhail. Like I said, I was curios to know how the web UI handles it (I don't have any datsets with that many tables), because the web UI is essentially just a wrapper around the BigQuery API.

Comment: in short: it takes some 30-40 sec and my users have same experience as it is described in  https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=669